# Erlang websocket error when connecting via Postman or Insomnia

Tags: websocket, erlang

Postman and insomnia return me a `Parse Error: Expected HTTP/` error when connecting to an Erlang Websocket and incidentally closes the `Accept Socket`.

Below is the module taken from `Learn You Some Erlang` book:

```
-module(naive_tcp).
-export([start_server/1]).
-export([acceptor/1]).

start_server(Port) ->
    Pid = spawn_link(fun() ->
            {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [binary, {active, false}]),
            spawn(fun() -> acceptor(Listen) end),
            timer:sleep(infinity)
        end),
    {ok, Pid}.

acceptor(ListenSocket) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
    spawn(fun() -> acceptor(ListenSocket) end),
    handle(Socket).

handle(Socket) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, <<"quit", _Rest/binary>>} ->
            gen_tcp:close(Socket);
        {ok, Packet} when is_binary(Packet) ->
            gen_tcp:send(Socket, Packet),
            handle(Socket);
        Other -> io:format("Received: ~p~n", [Other])
    end.
```

I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Insomnia request: `ws://localhost:8091`

```
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Eshell V12.2.1  (abort with ^G)
1> naive_tcp:start_server(8091).
{ok,<0.82.0>}
Received: {error,closed}
Received: {error,closed}
```

Comment: I don't know Erlang (I program in Elixir) but I have the feeling your client is expecting a websocket (the "ws' scheme in the URL) while your server seems to open and use an ordinary socket (hence the error message about HTTP expected).

Comment: I suspect that the term "websocket" isn't mentioned anywhere in the book "Learn You Some Erlang".  What's certain is: that module doesn't have anything to do with websockets.  If you want to create a server that can handle websocket connections, I think your best bet might be [Cowboy](https://ninenines.eu).   I also think there are  issues with the `handle(Socket)` function the way it was written because it may never read a binary that starts with "quit"--even if one was sent.

Comment: I think with the options your server uses, the only reliable way `handle()` will return is if the other side closes the socket and the case statement has an `{error, closed} ->` branch.

Comment: Yea, I think you mixed up between `socket` (general term for data communication between two endpoints in a network) and `websocket` (a specific protocol)